# sys sysprocesses in sql server list kpid 4056 but kpid not exist in server process

Tags: sql-server-2008, process, windows-server-2008, pid, spid

i am runnig query from `sys.sysprocesses`
one of the results is process with `kpid` '4056' and `SPId 390`
but when i saw the windows task manager or `tasklist` from command prompt
1-i tried to kill this process with `kill 390` in sql server:it doesnt kill and stay in kill/rollbak
2- i tried to kill via command prompt `taskkill /pid 4056`
it says that:"process with this `PID`  not exits."
anyway to kill this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my story it was failure of killing a process ran against Sharepoint with the following similar query and remaining in a  killed/rollback status for a long time. and i tried to resolve the issue without restarting sql server which i was not successful  but shows you where you can find the KPID  and how to kill them

```
SELECT  f1, f2
    FROM    OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                       'WSS;IMEX=1; DATABASE=http://portal.local/AA/XX/YY;LIST=Feedback;VIEW=;RetrieveIds=Yes;',
                       'SELECT   f1, f2  FROM LIST') AS derivedtbl_1
```

- use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find the right instance of sqlserver.exe by
  looking the location displayed in mouse over tooltip
- go to threads node and you will find the kernel thread there

  - but killing **it is not recommended** and will Hang SQL server and it make you to restart it in my case
- restart DTC(distributed Transaction Coordinator) service and SQL
  server agent service is another recommendation with may help killing the kpid safely in that machine

Comment: finally i kill the process by killing it from task mnager Process just you said .